# Sort a list with a custom order in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7

I have a list

`mylist = [['123', 'BOOL', '234'], ['345', 'INT', '456'], ['567', 'DINT', '678']]`

I want to sort it with the order of 1. `DINT` 2. `INT` 3. `BOOL`

Result:

`[['567', 'DINT', '678'], ['345', 'INT', '456'], ['123', 'BOOL', '234']]`

I've seen other similar questions in stackoverflow but nothing similar or easily applicable to me.

Comment: you have a syntax error: '345 is not closed.

Comment: "I want to sort it with the order of 1. DINT 2. INT 3. BOOL". What order is that? If I add another item `['317.3', 'FLOAT', '268.0']`, how do I know where it goes in the sorted output?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Well, the complete application of this is to sort REAL (float), DINT, INT, SINT, BOOL. This is the order I want (big to small). This question here is just for illustrative purpose. '123', '234', '345'... all has no real meaning.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
SORT_ORDER = {"DINT": 0, "INT": 1, "BOOL": 2}

mylist.sort(key=lambda val: SORT_ORDER[val[1]])
```

All we are doing here is providing a new element to sort on by returning an integer for each element in the list rather than the whole list.  We *could* use inline ternary expressions, but that would get a bit unwieldy.

Comment: @SeanVieira, how would you extend this when you have a sort order, but sometimes not all keys are in the list we want to sort?

Comment: Python has a `.get` method for dictionaries that can be used, so you could do `lambda val: SORT_ORDER.get(val[1], "MY DEFAULT SORT ORDER VALUE")` @joddm

Comment: Nice, but taking this as inspiration, I prefer `SORT_ORDER = ["DINT", "INT", "BOOL"]` `mylist.sort(key=lambda val: SORT_ORDER.index(val))`. I suppose maybe that's not as fast as using indexing? but it seems easier to interpret.

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be; set your order in a list:

```
indx = [2,1,0]
```

and create a new list with your order wished:

```
mylist = [mylist[_ind] for _ind in indx]

Out[2]: [['567', 'DINT', '678'], ['345', 'INT', '456'], ['123', 'BOOL', '234']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since that is not in aphabetical order I don't think there is one single function that can sort it but what you could do is create a new list and then append. This is kind of a cheap method of doing it; but it gets the job done.

```
newlist=[];
for sub_list in mylist:
     if(sub_list[1] == 'DINT']):
          newlist.append(sub_list);

for sub_list in mylist:
     if(sub_list[1] == 'INT']):
         newlist.append(sub_list);

for sub_list in mylist:
     if(sub_list[1] == 'BOOL']):
            newlist.append(sub_list);
```

Comment: Braces? `from __future__ import braces` ;-)  Also, see my answer - you only need to traverse the list once :-)

Comment: Yeah I prefer the other answer. Two-liner solution.

Comment: Even if this approach made sense, for the love of all that is holy, use list comprehensions, or `filter`, or something.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I don't know how you can say even if this approach made sense... I tested it and it works. But there is a thing called constructive criticism; no need to be rude to strangers.

Comment: One thing I always do when setting up loop(s) is try to think how I can reduce the number of passes through the data. In this case, you are looping through three times to find three different variables, so the challenge is finding a way where you can get all of your information in a single pass (since you will encounter all of the variables in a single pass). Sean's solution uses a dictionary to accomplish this, so each time you encounter an item you know exactly where it goes. Also, you should definitely take a look at list comprehensions - you'll quickly learn to love them :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey: Thanks, and that makes sense. I originally thought of somthing similar to that; I just wasn't sure if that method would work if elwc had multiple items had the same variable ex: 5 'INT's, 3 'DINT's and 4 'BOOL's. So I just thought it was safer to try that way; even though I did say it was the cheap method. :)

Comment: Ha, yeah, and it works so you can't knock it too hard :) Since Python sorts are stable, in the case of multiple occurrences, they will just return in the order they were passed into the sort function (so you were on the right track).

Answer (score 0):

You can define an explicit order by a list:

```
def explicit_order(xs):
    """Return a key function that, when passed to sort or sorted, will sort
    the elements in the order they appear in this list.
    """
    keys = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(xs)}
    def key_function(x):
        return keys[x]
    return key_function

order = explicit_order(['DINT', 'INT', 'BOOL'])
sorted(['BOOL', 'INT'], key=order) # = ['INT', 'BOOL']
```

Since in your example you also have to extract the string from your tuples, you'll have a slightly more complex key-function:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: order(x[1]))
```

Comment: Note that, as written, this throws if any items in the list to be sorted don't appear in the original list passed to `explicit_order`.

Answer (score -1):

python 3.2

1. `sorted(mylist,key=lambda x:x[1][1])`
2. `sorted(mylist,reverse=True)`

Comment: The first option works but assumes that the tag names won't change. The second option is not what the OP wants.