# Advanced custom sort

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I have a list of items that I would like to sort on multiple criterion.

Given input list:

```
cols = [
    'Aw H',
    'Hm I1',
    'Aw I2',
    'Hm R',
    'Aw R',
    'Aw I1',
    'Aw E',
    'Hm I2',
    'Hm H',
    'Hm E',
]
```

Criterions:

- Hm > Aw
- I > R > H > E

The output should be:

```
cols = [
   'Hm I1',
   'Aw I1',
   'Hm I2',
   'Aw I2',
   'Hm R',
   'Aw R',
   'Hm H',
   'Aw H',
   'Hm E',
   'Aw E'
]
```

I know this function needs to be passed onto the built-in `sorted()` but any ideas how to actually write it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208256/sort-a-list-with-a-custom-order-in-python   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624323/python-how-to-custom-order-a-list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write a function for the key, returning a `tuple` with each portion of interest sorted by priority.

```
def k(s):
    m = {'I':0, 'R':1, 'H':2, 'E':3}
    return m[s[3]], int(s[4:] or 0), -ord(s[0])

cols = [
    'Aw H',
    'Hm I1',
    'Aw I2',
    'Hm R',
    'Aw R',
    'Aw I1',
    'Aw E',
    'Hm I2',
    'Hm H',
    'Hm E',
]
```

Result:

```
>>> for i in sorted(cols, key=k):
...     print(i)
...
Hm I1
Aw I1
Hm I2
Aw I2
Hm R
Aw R
Hm H
Aw H
Hm E
Aw E
```

When sorting `tuple`s, the first elements are compared first. If they're the same, the `tuple`s are sorted by their second elements, and so on. This is similar to the way ordinary words are sorted alphabetically.

Since we first want all the elements with `'I'` together, then `'R'`, and so on, we'll put that first. To do that, we define a dictionary that gives each letter its desired priority. When we look up that letter (the fourth character in the string, `s[3]`) in that dictionary, there's the first part of the key.

Next, we want the number after that letter. For this, we'll use some short-circuiting to get either the fifth character and onward (`s[4:]`), or, if there aren't any, a `0`. We send that to `int`, which will evaluate the number as a number to put `'2'` after `'12'` like it should be.

Finally, if the first two parts are the same, items will be sorted based on their first character. If this was a simpler sort we could just specify `reverse=True`. If this part was a number, we could just take its negative. We'll just turn that character into a number with `ord()` and then take the negative of that.

The result is keys of, for example, `(0, 2, -65)` for `'Aw I2'`.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
cols = [
    'Aw H',
    'Hm I1',
    'Aw I2',
    'Hm R',
    'Aw R',
    'Aw I1',
    'Aw E',
    'Hm I2',
    'Hm H',
    'Hm E',
]

def compare(x, y):
    x1, x2 = x.split(' ')
    y1, y2 = y.split(' ')

    order = ['I1', 'I2', 'R', 'H', 'E']

    if order.index(x2) < order.index(y2):
        return -1
    elif order.index(x2) > order.index(y2):
        return 1
    else:
        if x1 == 'Hm' and y1 == 'Aw':
            return -1
        elif x1 == 'Aw' and y1 == 'Hm':
            return 1
    return 0

cols.sort(compare)
print(cols)
```

**Output**

```
['Hm I1', 'Aw I1', 'Hm I2', 'Aw I2', 'Hm R', 'Aw R', 'Hm H', 'Aw H', 'Hm E', 'Aw E']
```

Answer (score 1):

For comparing Aw, Hm and E, H, R, I etc you can define two dictionaries:

Now we need to parse each string into three components: **1.** (Aw or Hm) **2.** (E or H or R or I) **3.** Integer

Now using these components and the corresponding values from the dictionary we can return a tuple from our key function:

```
>>> import re
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> map_1 = {'Aw': 0, 'Hm': 1}
>>> map_2 = {'E': 0, 'H': 1, 'R': 2, 'I': 3}
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(Aw|Hm)\s([EHRI])(\d*)')
>>> def key_func(x):
    a, b, c = pattern.search(x).groups()
    return map_2[b], -int(c) if c else 0, map_1[a]
...
>>> pprint(sorted(cols, key=key_func, reverse=True))
['Hm I1',
 'Aw I1',
 'Hm I2',
 'Aw I2',
 'Hm R',
 'Aw R',
 'Hm H',
 'Aw H',
 'Hm E',
 'Aw E']
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's create something:

How about assigning points to your letters?

```
def custom_sort(string):
    value_dict = {'I':400 ,'R': 300,'H': 200,'E':100, 'Hm': 50, 'Aw':40}
    s = string.split()
    points = value_dict[s[0]] + value_dict[s[1][0]]
    if -len(s[1])>1:
        points -= int(s[1][1:])
    return -points

cols = [
    'Aw H',
    'Hm I1',
    'Aw I2',
    'Hm R',
    'Aw R',
    'Aw I1',
    'Aw E',
    'Hm I2',
    'Hm H',
    'Hm E',
]

print sorted(cols, key=custom_sort)
```