# Sort a list according to another list, with uneven length

Tags: python

Let's say I have two lists, l1 and l2:

```
l1 = [1,9,6,8,3]
l2 = [8,1]
```

The list l2 will be sorted according to the ordering of list l1, so in this case:

```
l2_reordered = [1,8]
```

Note: List l2 will always have 2 items which have a different value.

I can think of a naive loop approach to doing this, but that is going to be really inefficient. What is a pythonic and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe you should explain how you sort the second list a bit more clearly...

Comment: is the second list a filter?

Comment: Should it be ordered based on `l1`?

Comment: Agree! See the edit I made, hopefully it's more clear now

Comment: The edited question is clearer.  It sounds like every element in `l2` must be in `l1`.  The ordering matches the ordering in `l1`.  Can there be duplicates of a value? E.g. can `l2` be `[8, 1, 8]`?

Comment: List l2 will always have 2 different items. Will add this to the main question, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fast solution.  First build a `dict` mapping values to indices:

```
d = {v:i for i, v in enumerate(l1)}
```

Then use it to obtain sort keys:

```
r = sorted(l2, key=lambda v: d[v])
```

Creating `d` is O(len(l1)), and the sort is O(len(l2)*log(len(l2))).

Comment: +1 Our approaches are pretty similar but I suppose enumerate() is much faster than index(), plus you added the complexity analysis.

Comment: Also +1 for adding the time complexity

Comment: @MarcoD.G. Thanks!  Yeah calling `index` from within the dict comprehension would make the dict creation O(len(l1)**2), and there's no need since you're iterating over the elements anyway, so you just need to keep a count.  You could also iterate an index `i` over `range(len(l1))`, then use `l1[i]:i`.  `enumerate` is just a little more convenient.  Either way is O(len(l1)).

Answer (score 2):

```
SORT_ORDER = {_: l1.index(_) for _ in l1}
l2.sort(key=lambda _: SORT_ORDER[_])
```

Idea from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14208276/8411453)

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse l1 while matching it with l2 elements. Whenever you find an element you can mark that index of l1 or maybe store that index in a new list l3. Now in the end you can sort the l3 list based on index numbers.

```
for ele in l2:
   l3.append(l1.index(ele))
l3.sort()
i=0
for ele in l3:
   l2[i]=l1[ele]
   i+=1
```

The above code takes in all the values from l2, marks their index numbers in l1.Then we sort all the index numbers and put the sorted values in l2. Hope this can help a little.